# found black space on top and bottom Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have found black space on top and bottom in device even configure well. I don't think it's quite relevant to launch image. Please let me know how to fix it? [image]

Comment: Do you have any layout constraints in your IB?

Comment: Are you using a device or the simulator ?

Comment: @depicus using device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include Default images e.g Default.png,Default-568.png etc for all resolutions.This happens when app cannot find default image.

Comment: it's great that I used launch image instead of launch screen file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with iOS 7 devices, adding launch images fixed my issue.
ps make sure they are in the correct format:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Use asset Catalog" and Migrate for launch image source in target->General->App Icon and Launch Images.

Answer (score 1):

Due to not having Launch image for "Iphone 5" size( `Default-568h@2x.png` ) Your View pretend it as "Iphone 4" size device. 
That's the reason for blank space.

Answer is:

Add launch image Named as `Default-568h@2x.png` with `640x1136` size.

Let me knew if you need more help regarding this.